# count total checked checkboxes with value A

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count checked checkboxes which have value A. Below Code is working fine and giving me the desired result.

```
 $('#btn_submit').click(function ()  {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
       alert($(".multisteps-form__form input[value=A]:checked").length);

    });
});
```

But when i store it in var using below code then it is giving me count result 1 only. I don't know why..

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function ()  {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var Total_A = $('.multisteps-form__form input[value=A]:checked').length;
        alert($(Total_A).length);
      

    });
});
```

Comment: You already storing length of checked checkbox in `Total_A` and why are you doing in alert again `$(Total_A).length`, is  `Total_A` html element? no just alert only variable `Total_A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already stored the number of checked checkboxes to `Total_A`. So you don't need to get length of `Total_A` again.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    var Total_A = $(".multisteps-form__form input[value=A]:checked").length
  alert("Total: "+Total_A)

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class='multisteps-form__form'>
  <input type="checkbox" value="A">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A">
</div>
```

Comment: one more small thing i want to add text before count.... value should be like this   total:1

Comment: Just use `+` operator to add prefix to the number(added)

Comment: i am trying to add but then it is not counting... var Total_A = $("Total:"+".multisteps-form__form input[value=A]:checked").length

Comment: You added the `Total:` string to jquery selector(inside of $()). You shouldn't change that, just prepend the string to the result. Refer to my code here `alert("Total: "+Total_A)`
`